# How to prevent input type="number" taking e

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, meteor

I had a text field of type="text" but it is allowing e to be entered ..I even want to prevent that happening how can we do that?

```
  <input class="form-control" maxlength="12" ng-model="$ctrl.NumberInput" type="number"
   min="0" required focus>
```

Can someone help!

Comment: @Rob If i copy and paste it is still allowing e der

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following directive which will restrict only for numbers

```
app.directive('validNumber', function() {
  return {
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      if(!ngModelCtrl) {
        return; 
      }

      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(val) {
        if (angular.isUndefined(val)) {
            var val = '';
        }

        var clean = val.replace(/[^-0-9\.]/g, '');
        var negativeCheck = clean.split('-');
        var decimalCheck = clean.split('.');
        if(!angular.isUndefined(negativeCheck[1])) {
            negativeCheck[1] = negativeCheck[1].slice(0, negativeCheck[1].length);
            clean =negativeCheck[0] + '-' + negativeCheck[1];
            if(negativeCheck[0].length > 0) {
                clean =negativeCheck[0];
            }

        }

        if(!angular.isUndefined(decimalCheck[1])) {
            decimalCheck[1] = decimalCheck[1].slice(0,2);
            clean =decimalCheck[0] + '.' + decimalCheck[1];
        }

        if (val !== clean) {
          ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(clean);
          ngModelCtrl.$render();
        }
        return clean;
      });

      element.bind('keypress', function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode === 32) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/rvrtv5hL/)**

If you do not want to use directive use [`ng-pattern`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern)

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.numberInput"   ng-pattern="/[^0-9]/g" required />
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/9szaeeab/)**

Comment: Is der anyway without directive?

Comment: @HVarma check updated answer

Comment: It is still allowing e in your second demo rite>?

Comment: @HVarma yes it does, probably directive would be the answer

Comment: your first answer doesn't accept decimal, and second accepts 'e'

Comment: @mrid modified it

Comment: your first one's working fine !! but second is still kinda buggy

Comment: @Sajeetharan..Its working.I want to know this,will the use of directives have any impact on performance?

Comment: @HVarma It wont cause any issue until you use for many input boxes

Comment: @Sajeetharan can u help in this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41105598/how-to-disable-a-button-if-the-form-is-valid

Comment: sure i will do! what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

you can try the easiest way : [ng-pattern](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern)

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.numberInput"  ng-pattern="/^\d+$/" required />
```